# Appending content with jquery

Tags: jquery

Say we are attaching an error notification html/css pane/div to display some application layer errors returned from an ajax call out to server code. We branch on the presence of errors in the json response payload from the server and do the following:

```
$('#message').remove();
$('body').append('<div id="message" style="display: none;"><a href="" id="message-close">Close</a></div>');
$('#message-close').before(data['message'] + '<ul id="errors"><li>' + data['errors'].join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>');
$('#message').addClass('error').fadeIn();
```

This works just fine, but I would appreciate if people could point out improvements (basic or to make more elegant) or flaws on the jquery side that I might have missed. For instance, interspersing html fragments with jquery could be considered regrettable. By the way there is a click handler for #message-close defined elsewhere (as well as a success branch) as this is a redacted example. If this question belongs on the code review site instead of stackoverflow, please let me know. I haven't used the former, but am aware it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is definitely not more concise, but I think a programmatic approach scales as little bit better and is better suited for handling exceptions and corner cases (when they inevitably show up).

It also seems to read more straight forward than your example using `append` then `before` and so forth. This builds from the bottom up and nests data and event handlers as necessary.

```
$(function() {

    // simulate ajax call
    setTimeout(function() {

        // ajax datas
        var data = {errors: ['one', 'two', 'three']};

        // close handler
        var closeMessage = function() {
            $(this).parents("div").fadeOut();
            return false;
        };

        // render dialog
        $('<div id="message" style="display: none;"></div>').append(
            $('<ul id="errors"/>').append(
                $.map(data.errors, function(t) {
                    return $("<li/>").text("an error: "+t)[0];
                })))
            .append(
                $('<a href="#close" id="message-close">Close</a>')
                    .click(closeMessage))
            .appendTo("body")
            .fadeIn();

    }, 1000);

});
```

[See it working here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macek/pDJEw/)

Comment: I like your more functional bottom approach. Thank you for your thoughtful answer and taking the time to answer. I indicated that yours is an answer and I'd still like to see other answers if people come across this. For some reason, though I am logged in, every time I attempted to award you points it asked me to log in even though I have 'logout' available to me currently (never have had this problem before). Seems like SO is having an authentication issue at the moment (perhaps), though that would seem very unlikely. Anyhoo, thanks, I'd give you 5 points if I could currently.

Comment: Wow, they are really have an authentication issue. Though I am currently logged in as m7d, that is me, I can edit your answer (macek). It is like a session fixation attack without the cookie. Bizarre. Should make for an interesting day at SO.