# JQUERY load an array of elements into a DIV

Tags: jquery

I have an array of DIV elements in an array called 'noactiveMsg'.
I want to load these DIV elements into a DIV called `$('#chatCenterMembers')`.

I've tried:

```
noactiveMsg.appendTo($('#chatCenterMembers'));
```

But this doesn't work.
Can someone advice on the syntax to load an array of elements/objects into a div?

code to made the array:

```
var noactiveMsg=[];
 $('div.chatmember').each(function() {                        
 if($(this).children().children('div').hasClass('chatactivestatus_offline')) {
 alert('offline');
 noactiveMsg.push($(this));
 }              
 });
```

Comment: How was the array of DIVs created? Is each array element a separate jQuery object? Provide an actual code sample and this question will be answered for you in no-time flat.

Comment: I'ved added the code to make the array... thx

Comment: you're still not showing us where `noactiveMsg` is initialized. does it contain any elements before it gets to this section?

Comment: var noactiveMsg=[]; - sorry here is where its initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each element of your array is a jQuery object, you can try this:

---

Some sample html:

```
<div>
    <p>Some stuff below!</p>
</div>
```

---

The jQuery stuff:

```
$(function(){
    var foo = [];
    foo.push( $('<p>hello</p>') );
    foo.push( $('<p>world</p>') );
    foo.push( $('<p>Adam</p>') );

    // this will fail because each element is a 
    // separate jQuery object
    // $('div').append( foo );

    // instead try this
    $.each(foo, function(){
        $('div').append(this);
    })
});
```

[see it work on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VskXq/)

[I also answered a similar question just recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934168/appending-content-with-jquery/6934832)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code you need.
Assuming noactiveMsg is an array containing jQuery objects.

`cnt = noactiveMsg.length();`

for(i=0; i<cnt; i++) {

```
$('#chatCenterMembers').append(noactiveMsg[i].html());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to merge them all into one jQuery object:

```
var noactiveMsg = [$('<a>1</a>'), $('<a>1</a>')],
    collection;

$.each(noactiveMsg, function(i, e) {
    collection ? collection = collection.add(e) : collection = e;
});
```

**EDIT:**

Others have suggested adding every element in the array separately into the DOM. I would strongly advise you against it. Interacting with the DOM is an expensive operation, and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Hello @Joseph Silber, can you educate me some about the `.add()` method? Is this native to javascript? What exactly does it do?

Comment: @macek. Simply put: if you want to join two jQuery collections into one, you can use jQuery's `add()` method. This will not modify the original collections. It'll return a new collection that contains all the elements in both of those collections: http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: Thans @Joseph. That's a useful method :)